# Postgres - Generated Not-Stored Column

Tags: postgresql

According to [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html), one can create generated stored columns like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (
    ...,
    height_cm numeric,
    height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED
);
```

However, what if I want to have a column that is generated only when it is referenced and is not stored after use? Is that currently possible?

Comment: No, not possible as of Postgres 14 (and I don't see anything for Postgres 15 either)

Comment: Not available as of PG 14.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944643/does-postgresql-only-support-stored-generated-columns

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible in PostgreSQL, but it is not necessary either. Simply create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW people_i8 AS
SELECT ...,
       height_cm,
       height_cm / 2.54 AS height_in
FROM people;
```

Such a view can also be the target of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, so it should work fine for you.

Since views don't persist data (essentially, a reference to the view is replaces with the defining query), `height_in` is calculated when the view is queried.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if views generate columns only when you reference them? I.e. if have a `SELECT` clause that does not reference the `height_in` column, will it still get generated?